# Material UI: You have provided an out-of-range value for the select component, despite value being in the options list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an edit page with a material UI dropdown list of departments (values = id, name), which is being populated by and API.  When I select a record from my table, the record has a value of departmentName that I am using as my current value. The record's current value displays in the dropdown when the page loads, and if you open the dropdown to select a new value, the option matching the current value is highlighted.  Obviously the current value is on the list of options, but I am still getting this warning:

*Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value `(the current value)` for the select (name="departmentName") component. Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''. The available values are ``.*

How can I remedy this issue and get rid of this warning?  Can someone please show me what to do to fix this issue, I have tried everything I have seen online and nothing has taken care of the warning.

**Dropdown Component in form**

```
<Controls.Dropdown
  onChange={handleInputChange}
  name='departmentName'
  prompt='Select A Department...'
  url='/api/maintain/departments/'
  value={values.departmentName}
/>
```

**Dropdown**

```
export default function Dropdown(props) {
   const { error = null, label, onChange, prompt, value, url, ...other } = props;
   const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);

   React.useEffect(() => {
       const fetchData = async () => {
       const res = await axios.get(dropdownUrl);
       setOptions( res.data );
   };
   fetchData();
   }, [setOptions]); 

   return(
     <FormControl>
       <Select
         defaultValue=''
         onChange={onChange}
         value={value === undefined || null ? '' : value}
         {...other}
         {...(error && {error: true, helperText: error})}
     >
       <MenuItem value=''>{prompt}</MenuItem>
         {options && options.map((option, id) => (
           <MenuItem
           key={option.id}
           value={option.name}
         >
         {option.name}
       </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>
     </FormControl>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're passing a value to the `<Select>` before the `<MenuItem>` options have been populated.  Initially there are no options:

```
const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([]);
```

Only the default one:

```
<MenuItem value=''>{prompt}</MenuItem>
```

So if `value` is anything other than `null` or `undefined` (that check may have a bug too by the way, but we'll correct it as well) or `''` then it's a value which isn't in the available options.

During the time in which `options` is being populated by the AJAX operation, keep the selected value as `''` by default.  For example:

```
value={
  (value === undefined ||
  value === null ||
  options.length === 0) ? '' : value}
```

Comment: David, Thank you so much!  I have been trying to figure this out for over a day now, and after you explained it, it was so simple.